# On OS X, why does `sudo ls` show hidden (dot) files?

Tags: macos, ls, bsd

With OS X Yosemite, using the following commands, I get the following:

```
$ touch .a
$ touch b
$ /bin/ls
b
$ /bin/ls -A
.a  b
$ sudo /bin/ls
.a  b
```

It shows hidden files (that have names starting with a dot) when invoked by root and doesn’t show them (as expected) when running as a normal user. This differs from what `ls` on Linux (the one coming from `coreutils`) does.

Why does `ls` behave this way?

Comment: I misread those tags as "OSX is bad" and got really confused.

Comment: It would be less confusing if tags are allowed in uppercase, `BSD` and `OSX` are more appropriate here.

Comment: @Raystafarian quite funny, because normally is the other way around, people tries to write sentences with tags.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

It turns out this feature is not Apple-specific. This is a feature of BSD systems in general.

```c
/* Root is -A automatically. */
if (!getuid())
    f_listdot = 1;
```

Initially, I was able to trace it back to the sources of [4.4BSD-Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution#4.4BSD_and_descendants). It was already present in [this FreeBSD commit](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/e3cfc8ce61f788739c66445d903f8beacb40c93d#diff-a30c1f878c93e1e26c3202136ff6bf7eR117) from 1994 which is importing those sources.

The feature is also present in OpenBSD and can be found in [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/braindamaged/openbsd-src/src/a1b09369d5c0/bin/ls/ls.c#cl-132) from 1995 that claims to be importing code from NetBSD, so this was already present in [NetBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBSD).

Then one discovers the commit of NetBSD from 1993 that claims to be importing code from [386BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=386BSD), and the feature is already [there](https://github.com/jsonn/src/blob/c589a90df16e73a2ed13548cd02b0a70bb40c7da/bin/ls/ls.c#L115). Furthermore, [this commit](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/79b4d47f00826f8f26364ed06b785b51245db5f6/usr/src/bin/ls/ls.c#L115) shows that it was there during the development of 386BSD version 0.0 in 1991 which forked from BSD around 4.3, as far as I can tell.

The comment appeared for the first time during the development of [4.3BSD-Reno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution#4.3BSD) in [this commit](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/73adc5d219c3b410682916780f5acb057a4b8200#diff-5be2ee00918e5be9b9a88c50a3379165L67) (27 Jun 1989) entitled “first working version of new ls”. The original comment said:

```c
/* root sees all files automatically */
```

which was [changed later that day](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/587f69318c5558c4ac94721796dacbc6d76c06dd#diff-5be2ee00918e5be9b9a88c50a3379165L80) (I’m not sure the timestamps are entirely correct in this repository, though) to:

```c
/* root is -A automatically */
```

And only in 1992 the capital letter and the period [were added](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/aaa3304701dfb25efa8f9862d6bf1defd104e26a#diff-5be2ee00918e5be9b9a88c50a3379165L91) turning the comment into what we have now:

```c
/* Root is -A automatically. */
```

But the behaviour was present in 2BSD as of 9 May 1979 as seen in [this snapshot](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-2-Snapshot-Development/src/ls.c#L105):

```c
Aflg = getuid() == 0;
```

I can’t find any actual history from those times, but there is also [this snapshot](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-1-Snapshot-Development/.ref-Research-V6/usr/source/s1/ls.c) of 1BSD from 1977 *without* those lines. And without the `-A` flag actually.

So it seems that the feature was introduced somewhere between November of 1977 (1BSD being developed at that moment) and the release of 2BSD in May 1979.

---

What I also found during this investigation, is the `-I` flag that [was added](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/bb06a7834025d8fa0447c1e3e75c895e47730345) to FreeBSD in 2005 to override this behaviour and was [reworked](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/872d416547f20c6fefccc1b07c8bdc226632704c) a little bit later.

Comment: Also, it might be worth noting that the "feature" of hiding files by starting them with `.` was a simple bug - `ls` was only supposed to hide the `.` directory, not everything starting with `.`. Fast forward a few decades, and it's commonly used to hide dangerous files etc., while also being used to hide system configuration etc. - so it makes sense to let admins see those files (for maintaining the configuration or finding hidden malware etc.).

Comment: Reference for Luaan's comment: https://plus.google.com/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp (in which Rob Pike explains that hiding "dot files" started as a bug).

Comment: From the POSIX Rationale, "Some historical implementations of the ls utility show all entries in a directory except dot and dot-dot when a superuser invokes ls without specifying the -a option. When "normal" users invoke ls without specifying -a, they should not see information about any files with names beginning with a <period> unless they were named as file operands." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html

Comment: It's far far older. I think it predates the SysV-BSD split as last time I had access to SysV systems the exact same behavior was present.

Comment: @Joshua: I'm confused by your comment. This answer traces the feature to 1977-1979, which is before System V existed.

Comment: epic answer.  history learned!

Comment: Maybe it's just convergent then.

Answer (score 15):

Here's [a link](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-188/ls/ls.c) to the source code. Note `/* Root is -A automatically. */`. This is a feature in Apple's version of BSD `ls`.

Comment: Interesting find. Is there also a way to suppress hidden files when doing an ls?

Comment: Hm, [looks like](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2007-March/022861.html) this is not an Apple-specific feature, but it comes from the BSD world?

Comment: Right, it is not Apple-specific. Thanks for your answer, it put me on the right track. I used the `Root is -A automatically` string to search for clues.

Comment: Mr Lister: you can suppress the display of the dot files as root with -I (capital i) on many operating systems (FreeBSD, so probably OS X as well)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, there was a thread about this back in the early days of Usenet (early 80's). The feature was added as a security precaution so that malicious users couldn't easily hide files/directories/executables from the sysadmin/root. The theory was basically "root has access to everything so it should be able to see everything".

Comment: Sounds reasonable (even though turning a file into dot-file is a questionable way of “hiding” it). Would be great to find those archives.